# Opensea token URI version v2 return success false error

Tags: ethereum, web3js, opensea

I am trying to fetch the metadata out of a token URI which I found inside an NFT. The token URI looks like this:

`https://api.opensea.io/api/v2/metadata/matic/<contract_address>/0x{id}`

I tried using the hex form of the tokenId instead of {id} but it just returns `{ success:false }` error on `GET` call.

Why is that I am getting this error? I placed my token Id in the form of hex instead of `0x{id}`.

Comment: I'm facing same issue even if I provide an OpenSea API Key.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know the rate-limit on opensea API causes this issue - just leave it for a few hours and see if it persists.

Opensea did not provide any useful information with regards to their api throttling in the documentation.

https://docs.opensea.io/

Comment: But rate limiting should be throwing a throtling error, the error doesnt specify anything